# Linux лезет в интернет

Tags: linux, redhat

Собственно проблема с установкой пакетов. Пытаюсь поставить 1с на сервер и при установке он пытается что-то скачать. Доступа в интернет у сервера нет. Подумал дай я удалю старую версию и установлю новую, может проблема где-то здесь. Но как оказалось нет, при попытке вывести все установленные пакеты `yum list` точно такая же ситуация, хочет что-то скачать. Раньше такого замечено небыло. Как мне отключить такое поведение, доступ в интернет давать не желательно. Скрин как раз после команды `yum list`.

PS извиняюсь что скрин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `fastmirror` отключать пробовал?

Comment: @Fat-Zer пробовал, не помогло

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov попробуйте `yum list  --disablerepo=*`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Огромное спасибо! помогло! можно вынести в ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yum пытается обратиться к репозиториям, которые включены, для получения update-ов. 
для того, чтобы запретить это действие, можно отключить все репы  `--disablerepo=*`, также можно и определенные.

если какой-то репозиторий вам больше не нужен, то вы можете его выключить `yum update -y --disablerepo=myrepo`,  либо аккутратно переименовать `myrepo.repo` на `myrepo.repo.off`. Репозитории находятся в /etc/yum.repos.d/